# What does SO have that we don't? Syntax highlighting

Tags: support

Syntax highlighting! Mike asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770464/pic16f-sspadd-causing-scl-to-go-low-early) on SO, and the code looks like this:

[image]

Then he [moved the question to EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37052/pic16f-sspadd-causing-scl-to-go-low-early), which is sensible, because we're so much smarter than them on SO, but here his code looks like this:

[image]

What happened to the syntax highlighting?

Comment: Contacted community managers, it was the [tag:c]. Edited in, better?

Comment: @Kortuk - Yes, it's OK now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of our source code questions don't specify a programming language in the tags. I'm not sure if we want every question that has code in it to be tagged with a language, but there is a simple workaround - you can add a header to force a language.

For reference, see the [syntax highlighting for code](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) segment of the advanced editing help guide. The only language that we use that isn't supported is Verilog.

Comment: I am of the feeling that if it involves programming tagging it with the language is valuable, but that may be just me!

Comment: @Kortuk heh... more tag cleanup :). Can we set a default code formatting for [tag:arduino]?

Comment: They mostly already have the correct formatting, but things like arduino do not, good call.

Comment: Has anyone posted a request for Verilog code highlighting on the Markdown/SO meta sites?

Comment: @SimpleCoder The issue is that there are not formatting rules for Verilog in the Google Prettify project. You would first need to have a syntax ruleset designed by the Prettify project before it could be implemented here.

Answer (score 4):

Syntax highlighting rules are decided by what language the question is tagged with. Sadly the source question has already been deleted, so I cannot see what tags it had but there should be a tag that gives the necessary highlighting. If not, moderators can tie tags to certain programming language highlighting.

Comment: I still have the original question open on one of my Firefox  50 tabs :-). It's indeed tagged "c".

Comment: @stevenvh not sure why c was dropped.

Comment: When you copy the body text of the question you can't include the tags. He remembered two of them, just forgot the third.

Comment: @stevenvh that is not the proper way to move a post. It should have been migrated from SO. A flag to a moderator requesting it would have had a moderator handle it. It would also show up in statistics. That is more similar to cross posting which is not encouraged.

Comment: *I* know all that, tell it to Mike! :-) I told him about the cross posting.

Comment: @stevenvh Ohh, well then. I blame W5VO for this confusion.

Comment: Yeah, these new moderators are a godsend ;-)